# Error: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got nil)

Tags: mysql, lua, mysql-proxy, luasql

I am trying to connect to a mysql server using LuaSql via a mysql proxy. I try to execute a simple program (db.lua):

```
require("luasql.mysql")
local _sqlEnv = assert(luasql.mysql())
local _con = nil

function read_auth(auth)
local host, port = string.match(proxy.backends[1].address, "(.*):(.*)")
_con = assert(_sqlEnv:connect( "db_name", "username", "password", "hostname", "3306"))
end 

function disconnect_client()
assert(_con:close())
end 

function read_query(packet)
local cur = con:execute("select * from t1")
myTable = {}
row = cur:fetch(myTable, "a") 
print(myTable.id,myTable.user)
end
```

This  code executes well when I execute it without `mysql-proxy`. When I am connecting with mysql-proxy, the error-log displays these errors:

mysql.lua:8: bad argument #1 to 'insert' (table expected, got nil)
    db.lua:1: loop or previous error loading module 'luasql.mysql'

mysql.lua is a default file of LuaSql:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MySQL specific tests and configurations.
-- $Id: mysql.lua,v 1.4 2006/01/25 20:28:30 tomas Exp $
---------------------------------------------------------------------

QUERYING_STRING_TYPE_NAME = "binary(65535)"

table.insert (CUR_METHODS, "numrows")
table.insert (EXTENSIONS, numrows)

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Build SQL command to create the test table.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
local _define_table = define_table
function define_table (n)
        return _define_table(n) .. " TYPE = InnoDB;"
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MySQL versions 4.0.x do not implement rollback.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
local _rollback = rollback
function rollback ()
        if luasql._MYSQLVERSION and string.sub(luasql._MYSQLVERSION, 1, 3) == "4.0" then
                io.write("skipping rollback test (mysql version 4.0.x)")
                return
        else
                _rollback ()
        end
end
```

Comment: What does this mean: "connecting with mysql-proxy"? Is this a module? A script? How do you use it?

Comment: @Schollii it is a lua script(db.lua) that i specify in my mysql-proxy.cnf file of mysql proxy.I use it through mysql proxy to access mysql server from mysql-proxy..Am i clear?

Comment: Based on the [mysql-proxy docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-proxy-scripting-read-query.html) and the code you posted I am guessing that you are trying to script mysql-proxy rather than connect to a mys1l server through a mysql proxy. In that case what do you mean by "executes well when i execute them without myql-proxy". The error you get means that the proxy does not create the CUR_METHODS table. What makes you think that creating a db connection from within the proxy is allowed?

Comment: @Schollii What i mean by "executes well when i execute them without myql-proxy" is i can connect to mysql database using LuaSql,but i am unable to connect the same with mysql-proxy.Is it possible to connect mysql server via mysql-proxy? P.S: Now i have made some changes in the code..So please check it now

Comment: @Schollii i also have another doubt is it possible to use luasql script through mysql proxy?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my previous comment, the error indicates that `table.insert (CUR_METHODS, ...)` is getting a nil as first arg. Since the first arg is `CUR_METHODS`, it means that this object `CUR_METHODS` has not been defined yet. Since this happens near top of the `luasql.mysql` module, my guess is that the `luasql` initialization was incomplete, maybe because the mysql DLL was not found. My guess is that the `LUA_CPATH` does not find the MySQL DLL for luasql, but I'm surprised that you wouldn't get a package error, so something odd is going on. You'll have to dig into the `luasql` module and C file to figure out why it is not being created.

Update: alternately, update your post to show the output of `print("LUA path:", package.path)` and `print("LUA path:", package.cpath)` from your mysql-proxy script and also show the path of folder where luasql is installed and contents of that folder.

Comment: but mysql.so is present at a particular.I specified that path in the mysql-proxy.cnf for LUA_CPATH.But still the same error.

Comment: @robin you accepted this answer, but your last comment indicates still problem, can you clarify what is actual status?

Comment: the status is that the same error prevails even after changing the LUA_CPATH.

Comment: i got it the actual mistake is in including the right LUA_CPATH in the mysql-proxy config file.It works well now :) Thanks for your help.